# I want create two intent one for activate doctor and second for deactivate doctor having trouble

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I created two intents-
a. activate doctor
training phase: activate doctor 9292929292

b. deactivate doctor
training phase: deactivate doctor 9292929292

Now when in input -"activate doctor 9393939393" then it detects deactivate Intent.  which is wrong

**activate/deactivate** - I created it admin entity.
**doctor** - userType entity.
**9292929292** - is phone-number type entity

Comment: can you give more brief do you want to create two intents or want to solve issue with entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you. I found this solution

**activate**   - associate it with activate entity
**deactivate** - associate it with deactivate entity

I create 2 different entity for confusing commands. I also like the solution by: Mohamed Halat

Answer (score 0):

If you really want 2 different intents you can turn off ML kit on them so that it doesn't confuse the two.

[image]

Comment: hmm..nice solution I solve this in other way  Create 2 different entity for commands:

activate  - associate it with activate entity
deactivate - associate it with deactivate entity